# ARIMA model with extremely small estimated $\sigma^2$ in log-transformed data

Tags: time-series, variance, data-transformation, arima, prediction-interval

I analyzed a time series data set using ARIMA model. And if I fit an ARIMA model using the original data, the estimated $\sigma^2$ is in the normal range, say 100. But when fit the same model using the log-transformed data, the estimated $\sigma^2$ becomes extremely small, say 0.00001. Note that the variance of the original data is about 8000 and the variance of the log-transformed data is 0.002.

Is this normal? If so, how can I make prediction intervals using the model based on log-transformed data (because the se is so small)?

Answer (score 2):

Of course the estimate of the variance parameter on the log scale is very different.  They're not in the same units, and describe quite different things about the distribution on the original scale.

The low value (though it's not actually so low) suggests that the relative variation about the model is smallish (in essence, that the conditional coefficient of variation is fairly small).

But not astonishingly so -- if the estimated conditional variance on the log-scale is 0.002, the standard deviation is about 0.045, so a 95% prediction interval on the original scale would be on the order of $\pm 9.5\%$ of the mean prediction. This is modest, but doesn't seem especially small (well, in fact they could be considerably wider, depending on the impact of parameter uncertainty -- assuming your software attempts to take account of that)

> If so, how can I make prediction intervals using the model based on log-transformed data(because the se is so small)?

In the absence of a clear mention of a specific problem you are seeing (does the model not fit in some way? We can't tell), I don't see how a small standard error necessarily implies any difficulty at all.

Once you take prediction intervals back to the original scale, if the model is appropriate those limits should appear quite suitable.